# Ubuntu 20.04 boot slowdown due to some services

Tags: boot, 20.04, boot-time

I'm using *ubuntu 20.04 LTS*. The boot time is **increased** drastically. How can I **decrease** the boot time? Which services can be **stopped**?

Here is the output of `systemd-analyze blame` :

```
2min 1.371s connman-wait-online.service                          
1min 29.696s nmbd.service                                         
     39.727s mysql.service                                        
     34.196s udisks2.service                                      
     30.499s man-db.service                                       
     30.076s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
     28.287s postgresql@12-main.service                           
     25.887s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
     23.571s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
     23.567s snapd.service                                        
     22.759s logrotate.service                                    
     20.528s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
     19.988s tor@default.service                                  
     19.236s dev-sda5.device                                      
     13.308s accounts-daemon.service                              
     12.483s apache2.service                                      
     11.346s polkit.service                                       
     10.809s dev-loop21.device                                    
     10.805s avahi-daemon.service                                 
     10.802s bluetooth.service                                    
     10.792s NetworkManager.service                               
     10.779s connman.service                                      
     10.769s dundee.service                                       
     10.762s ofono.service                                        
     10.731s dev-loop11.device                                    
     10.664s dev-loop23.device                                    
     10.611s dev-loop18.device                                    
     10.510s dev-loop17.device                                    
     10.501s dev-loop28.device                                    
     10.415s switcheroo-control.service                           
     10.410s thermald.service                                     
     10.394s wpa_supplicant.service                               
     10.386s systemd-logind.service                               
     10.371s dev-loop27.device                                    
     10.217s dev-loop19.device                                    
     10.139s vboxdrv.service                                      
      9.931s dev-loop25.device                                    
      9.865s dev-loop26.device                                    
      9.703s dev-loop8.device                                     
      9.581s dev-loop20.device                                    
      9.229s dev-loop22.device                                    
      9.060s dev-loop16.device                                    
      8.922s dev-loop9.device                                     
      8.919s dev-loop15.device                                    
      8.888s dev-loop24.device                                    
      8.305s dev-loop10.device                                    
      8.210s dev-loop7.device                                     
      8.014s ModemManager.service                                 
      7.848s dev-loop12.device                                    
      7.073s dev-loop0.device                                     
      6.946s dev-loop3.device                                     
      6.837s dev-loop1.device                                     
      6.834s dev-loop14.device                                    
      6.497s redis-server.service                                 
      6.457s dev-loop5.device                                     
      6.321s dev-loop2.device                                     
      6.296s systemd-resolved.service                             
      6.218s dev-loop13.device                                    
      6.124s gpu-manager.service                                  
      6.052s dev-loop6.device                                     
      5.453s dev-loop4.device                                     
      4.993s fwupd.service                                        
      4.530s rsyslog.service                                      
      3.600s apt-daily-upgrade.service                            
      3.543s grub-common.service                                  
      3.462s apport.service                                       
      3.450s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-18B7\x2d5624.service
      3.000s plymouth-read-write.service                          
      2.986s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
      2.882s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
      2.421s systemd-udevd.service                                
      2.234s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-95.mount                 
      2.120s snap-chromium-1373.mount                             
      2.032s snap-chromium-1382.mount                             
      2.023s snap-core-10126.mount                                
      2.004s snap-core-10185.mount                                
      1.914s ssh.service                                          
      1.895s apparmor.service                                     
      1.769s snap-core18-1885.mount                               
      1.656s snap-core18-1932.mount                               
      1.627s snapd.seeded.service                                 
      1.611s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-100.mount              
      1.610s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-98.mount               
      1.492s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount              
      1.488s networking.service                                   
      1.448s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount              
      1.409s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount               
      1.320s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount               
      1.298s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-145.mount            
      1.297s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-148.mount            
      1.267s snapd.apparmor.service                               
      1.219s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
      1.198s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1502.mount              
      1.196s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount              
      1.091s snap-heroku-3997.mount                               
      1.090s snap-heroku-3999.mount                               
      1.010s sysstat.service                                      
      1.008s xl2tpd.service                                       
       978ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
       970ms systemd-modules-load.service                         
       899ms systemd-random-seed.service                          
       897ms smbd.service                                         
       830ms gdm.service                                          
       730ms snap-insomnia-105.mount                              
       703ms tlp.service                                          
       673ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
       649ms snap-insomnia-109.mount                              
       594ms systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service   
       588ms snap-qt551-30.mount                                  
       584ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
       534ms systemd-journald.service                             
       490ms snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-214.mount                  
       483ms upower.service                                       
       476ms keyboard-setup.service                               
       465ms snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-211.mount                  
       463ms plymouth-start.service                               
       463ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
       440ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
       421ms swapfile.swap                                        
       417ms openvpn@client.service                               
       405ms dns-clean.service                                    
       384ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
       358ms snap-vlc-1620.mount                                  
       341ms pppd-dns.service                                     
       339ms binfmt-support.service                               
       331ms snap-scrcpy-254.mount                                
       324ms snap-scrcpy-243.mount                                
       296ms snap-qt551-29.mount                                  
       253ms ifupdown-pre.service                                 
       250ms snap-vlc-1700.mount                                  
       234ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
       224ms alsa-restore.service                                 
       205ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
       203ms colord.service                                       
       198ms apport-autoreport.service                            
       195ms openvpn.service                                      
       189ms user@1000.service                                    
       170ms console-setup.service                                
       144ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
       144ms tor.service                                          
       131ms kerneloops.service                                   
       127ms blueman-mechanism.service                            
       126ms ufw.service                                          
       116ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
       116ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
       109ms boot-efi.mount                                       
        87ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service                      
        86ms vboxautostart-service.service                        
        59ms setvtrgb.service                                     
        59ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
        56ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
        55ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
        54ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
        54ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
        41ms vboxweb-service.service                              
        39ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
        37ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                        
        28ms packagekit.service                                   
        18ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
        16ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
         1ms postgresql.service                                   
       759us snapd.socket
```

**Update:**
After removing snap and disabling services which are not required, this is the updated output:

```
1min 18.932s apport-autoreport.service                            
     18.404s udisks2.service                                      
     13.156s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
     10.534s accounts-daemon.service                              
      9.833s tor@default.service                                  
      7.489s polkit.service                                       
      7.049s switcheroo-control.service                           
      6.946s avahi-daemon.service                                 
      6.939s NetworkManager.service                               
      6.929s connman.service                                      
      6.917s dundee.service                                       
      6.869s ofono.service                                        
      6.774s ModemManager.service                                 
      6.652s thermald.service                                     
      6.652s systemd-logind.service                               
      6.630s wpa_supplicant.service                               
      6.538s dev-sda5.device                                      
      6.221s vboxdrv.service                                      
      4.375s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
      4.188s gpu-manager.service                                  
      3.881s ssh.service                                          
      3.861s grub-common.service                                  
      3.456s xl2tpd.service
```

Comment: Seem to have too many that just disabling some would fix.  Would imagine that something else is causing the slow down.  Can you remember anything that happen just before system started to get slow boot?

Comment: The boot time was increased slowly so I'm not sure about any particular service. Now, I'm disabling services that are not useful like database-services. I'm also purging the fu*king snap from my distro.

Comment: I guess those dev-loops are because of the snapd.

Comment: The dev-loops are for snaps and do slow down boot time.  Some people just remove snaps/snapd.  Would use google to find which other services safe to disable.  Most of your stuff is over 5 seconds, which is why I think something is causing the slow down.  How full is your drive?

Comment: 30-35% is available.

Comment: Would try to keep that amount free.  Should of asked about partition/s(should have same amount free).

Comment: According to your output, looks like you have been experimenting: Your system seems to be starting both mysql AND postgresql, NetworkManager AND connman AND networkd. Consider uninstalling some of those duplicate services. Remember to clean up after you finish experimenting.

Comment: @user535733 yup, there is an update.

Comment: @user535733 I have disabled connman as well. Now it's better.